# Linking to static asset (PDF) in Remix?

Tags: remix

I want to add a link, in a component, that points to a PDF document that resides in the application codebase:

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
    ...
    return <a href="../../shared-assets/some-pdf.pdf">Download</a>
}
```

I have added it to both the `public` folder and also tried in a custom folder (`shared-assets`) in the root of the project. Both time it just wasn't finding the file - probably because the route for this file doesn't exist (not sure how I would set this up).

I also tried importing it like an image but this threw an error in the terminal "No loader is configured for '.pdf' files".

```
import somePdf from '../../shared-assets/some-pdf.pdf';
...
<a href={somePdf}>Download</a>
```

So how do I get this working?

Answer (score 2):

Static content should be stored in the *./public* folder.

So *./public/shared-assets/some-pdf.pdf*

The link would be `<a href="/shared-assets/some-pdf.pdf">Download</a>`

Files in *./public* are relative to the root `/` URL.

As for importing the file, only file extensions listed [here](https://github.com/remix-run/remix/blob/main/packages/remix-dev/modules.ts) are handled. Unfortunately, PDF is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a [resource route](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/resource-routes) file `$filename[.pdf].tsx`,  the contents of which were:

```
import { readFileSync } from 'fs'
import sanitize from 'sanitize-filename'

const getFileContents = (filename: string) => readFileSync(`./public/shared-assets/${sanitize(filename)}.pdf`)

type ParamsType = {
  filename: string
}

export async function loader({ params }: { params: ParamsType }) {
  const { filename } = params
  const pdf = getFileContents(filename)
  return new Response(pdf, {
    status: 200,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
    },
  })
}
```